# Prevent Form from closing when DialogResult is No

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, forms, dialog

I am using following code on closing event of my Windows forms application form:

```
private void Main_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    DialogResult dr = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to quit?", "Leaving App",MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
    if (dr == DialogResult.No)
    {
        return;
    }
    else
    Application.Exit();
}
```

But the problem is, whenever user clicks Yes the application ends but when user clicks No, the application is still running but the form hides. How can I keep form visible when user clicks No?

**Update**

Another problem I am facing is that, when I click Yes, the MessageBox displays again and then I click Yes the application exits. Why its displaying for two times?

Comment: can't remember exactly but I think its `e.Cancel = true`, while your at it remove the `Application.Exit`

Comment: For your second problem, put a breakpoint in formclosing and take a look at the stack trace to see what is calling form closing

Comment: thanks for your answer @Sayse, I found another way for my second problem. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't have to call `Application.Exit()` because if you do not cancel closing it program will exit itself. Below is corrected code that is working:

```
private void Main_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    DialogResult dr = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to quit?", "Leaving App",MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
    if (dr == DialogResult.No)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. But another problem I am facing is that, when I click Yes, the MessageBox displays again and then I click Yes the application exits. Why its displaying for two times?

Comment: Do you have close button? Maybe you are asking there as well and that is why it is prompting two times.

Comment: thanks @gzaxx, but I figured out another way of doing it that suits my application's work flow. :)

Answer (score 7):

```
private void Form1_Closing(Object sender, CancelEventArgs e) {
   if (!isDataSaved) {
      e.Cancel = true;
      MessageBox.Show("You must save first.");
   }
   else {
      e.Cancel = false;
      MessageBox.Show("Goodbye.");
   }
}
```

[Source: MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.canceleventargs.cancel.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

you need to cancel the exit using `e.Cancel = true;` in your event `Main_FormClosing` to stop from closing

Answer (score 1):

I know it is not the correct way but it will result as you want.

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
   if(MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to quit?", "Leaving App", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo).ToString()=="No")
        e.Cancel = true;
}
```

Because of ToString() method will provide the result of the dialog box when used with a message box.

Answer (score 1):

I am Akhilavishnu, for more help please mail me akhilavishnu2@gmail.com. Please put these lines of codes in your application it works well happy coding.

```
private void    Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if(MessageBox.Show("Are you sure that you want to exit", 
                        MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, 
                        MessageBoxIcon.question) == DialogResult.No)
    {
        e.Cancel=true;
    }
}

//in formclose event
private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender,FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    Application.Exit();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just put the following code into the click event for your exit button, it works fine :)

```
DialogResult quit = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to quit?", "Quit", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question)
if (quit == DialogResult.Yes) this.Close();
```